# How do I headlessly create a page in Wagtail?

Tags: python, django, wagtail, headless-cms

Is there any way I mimic the Wagtail behaviour of creating pages?

The only way that I can think of is to totally replicate the `POST` request sent by them upon clicking 'Publish' in the admin interface, but that would be just hideous.

I need this because I need to get a product list from an api, treat them and insert them in my DB. I would prefer to do this through wagtail so I do not drift away from my CMS

In a perfect world this would be a call to some api endpoint where I provide the needed fields in the body of the request.

Comment: Wagtail pages are just Django models – you can well create them programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use management command (or any other trigger) to do something like:

```
from wagtail.core.models import Page

from myapp.models import CustomPage


parent_page = Page.objects.filter(slug="parent_page")[0] # get a suitable parent 

page = CustomPage(
        title="Sample name",
        depth=4,
        path="Some random path",
 )

parent_page.add_child(instance=page)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a management command.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/